# OAuth in Websphere Application Server 8.5 ND

Tags: oauth, websphere

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1305_odonnell1/1305_odonnell1.html
Using the above link 
I have enabled OAuth on the WebSphere Application Server 8.5 ND. The OAuth application is up and running.
I am even able to get a acess_token from the authorization.
But when I use the Acess token to authenticate the snoop Servlet, I get a pop up to enter Username and Password.
Tried, reinstalling the application on the server. 
The Application says "Default Realm" Am I missing out anything here? 
Please help.

thanks,
Naveen S

Comment: Help us help you.  As suggested in the article, rerun your scenario with the following trace string: com.ibm.ws.security.oauth20.*=all.  Post the output here so we can have a look.

Comment: How do I enable trace for just that string.

Answer (score 0):

A error here ESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user.

You can disable Security Integration check box in websphare console:

Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Session management.

You can find the answer here:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187598/how-can-we-disable-the-exception-sesn0008e-a-user.html